# Ruby Fog gem: how to create sub-directories?

Tags: ruby, fog, fog-aws

I have

```
  connection = Fog::Storage.new(fog_config)
  bucket     = connection.directories.get(bucket_name)
```

Is there a way (documented, non-documented, work-around) for me to create directories inside of this bucket? Something like:

```
sub_dir_for_user_1 = bucket.create_sub_dir('/user_1_files')
sub_dir_for_user_2 = bucket.create_sub_dir('/user_2_files')
```

Comment: AFAIK Amazon S3 doesn't have the concept of directories, it's a flat file system. Directories are only presented in the browser UI for convenience.

Comment: Yeah, there are no true directories in S3, just long paths (where in some contexts prefixes delineated by slashes are treated kind-of-like subdirectories).

Answer (score 8):

In S3 zero byte files with a trailing slash will create a pseudo-directory.  Which will cause folders to appear in the AWS Browser UI.

For fog passing nil into the body argument creates an empty file.  So the following code would create a subdirectory...

```
bucket.files.create(
  key: 'user_1_files/',
  body: nil
)
```